# How does one write an HTML-like filename field in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, getopenfilename

I'm making an auto-generated Tkinter GUI (like an HTML form), and I'm trying to make a filename field like the one HTML uses.
Here is my code:

```
e = ttk.Entry(master)
e.grid(row=ROW, column=1)
b = ttk.Button(master, text="...")
b.grid(row=ROW, column=2, sticky=tkinter.E)
```

I want it to be so that when the user clicks the `...` button, a filename dialog pops up (I know how to do that part), and when the user selects a file, it is reflected in the entry (this is the part I have trouble on).
The reason why I have trouble on that part is that E and B constantly change because this is run in a loop, so I think the only way to make this work is to use a row detector, and somehow change the value of the Entry box. How would I do this?

Thanks in advance! If this is by any means unclear, please let me know.

Comment: "The reason why I have trouble on that part is that E and B constantly change because this is run in a loop". Elaborate? Sounds like you should put `e` and `b` in a class.

Comment: E and B as in the variable that stores the Entry and the Button. And they are already in a class. What should I do with them?

Comment: How do they change constantly? Do you recreate them?

Comment: Yes, this is within a loop. I could use a dictionary to store them, but my problem is that even if I could access a copy of them, how would I change the value on the screen? A copy doesn't do me much good, because I need the real thing to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best solutions is to create your own widget as a class. Something like this:

```
class MyWidget(self, tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.button = tkinter.Button(self, text="...",
                                     command=self._on_button)
        self.button.pack(side="right")
        self.entry.poack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

    def _on_button(self):
        s = <call whatever dialog you want...>
        if s != "":
            self.entry.delete(0, "end")
            self.entry.insert(0, s)

...
entry = MyWidget(master)
entry.grid(...)
...
```